# how to use <tr1/unordered_map> in Xcode5

Tags: xcode5

I update the Xcode to Xcode5 on OSX 1.8.5 and there is a error that 'tr1/unordered_map' file not found, I set the C++ Language Dialect in GNU++11 GNU++98 C++11 C++98 and set C++ Standard Library with libc++ and libstdc++ but the error is still.
I can found the file on my disk /usr/local/includ